# How can I install PostgreSQL using the command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, installation, postgresql

I have problems with installing PostgreSQL. I tried to download PostgreSQL Version 9.6.1 for Windows x86-64 from enterprisedb.com.

I have the widespread problem, that the prompt "Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster" shows up, when I try to install PostgreSQL.

So I googled my problem and I found a tutorial here http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/install-postgresql/ which should solve my problem.

It says:

> You need to do the following steps:
>
> 1. Uninstall the PostgreSQL and delete the data directory in the installation folder
> 2. Create a new Windows user named postgres and add it to the Administrators group
> 3. Restart your computer
> 4. Open cmd (command prompt)
>    as the postgres command using the following command: runas
>    /user:postgres cmd.exe
> 5. A new window appears, you need to run the
>    installer file from this window.

I did steps 1 - 3. Then I opened the command prompt and typed "runas /user:postgres cmd.exe" Then this Window appeared:

[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsRXV.png)

And now I don't have a clue, what to type in there in order to run the postgreSQL installer. I have no experience with command prompts. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Did you actually get the error message described in that tutorial or did you just get "an error"?

Comment: I did get the first error message "Failed to load sql modules into the database cluster". I'm not sure about the second message anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the directory (`cd`) to the one where you downloaded the PostgreSQL installer to and just type in the name of the executable and hit enter.

As an example:

```
cd C:\Users\<User>\Download\
PostgreSQL-Installer.exe
```

Or just use the whole path (be careful with spaces):

```
C:\Users\<User>\Download\PostgreSQL-Installer.exe
```

Another option would've been to rightclick while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and selecting "Run as different User" or "Run as administrator". Both methods might not working depending on whenver administrative priviliges or a separate user account are actually needed.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I get the same error. Before the installation it said that i still have "PostgreSQL" on my C:-folder, and that it will overwrite this "PostgreSL"-folder. However I can't find any PostgreSQL-folder on C:, as i deleted them all. Very strange.

Comment: Maybe take a snap of the actual message during installation? That could be valuable information. If it tells you about that folder it has to be somewhere. The default Path would be `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6`. Did you customize the paths to the installation folder or data folder? Did you consider trying to install it to a folder that is not `C:\Program FIles` and give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with your default password for postgres user in windows, you should just remove the `Stack Builder` check in installer wizard.
[default password for postgres user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8j7K.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).